# Share sticky notes on multiple computers

Tags: windows, collaboration, synchronization

I am looking for windows application which will allow me and my collegue to share some notes.

Right now I am using Windows sticky notes. I was able to link sticky notes file to dropbox any sync it to second computer. Using mklink command.

This works fine but "offline" - I have to close notes on the first station and run on the second one. If both stations are running it is causing conflicts.

It seems to me that this default windows app is not capable to do that. Any tip for something allways on top able to do online sync?

Preferably free

Thank you for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean Windows sticky notes or specific what...
But have you look at Microsoft One Notes ?
https://www.onenote.com/

Comment: Thank you. I have created onenote book on shared folder and it works exactly as I expected.

Comment: Good. I am glad to hear that. I use that a lot at my desk.

Answer (score 0):

Tree-structured hierarchical online note-taker.

https://webnote.in/